# php sockets with proxy

Tags: php, sockets, proxy

I want to use php sockets via proxy. I use the following code for socket create

```
    $socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);
    $result = socket_connect($socket, some_ip, 443);
```

And setting the proxy via :

```
$aContext = array(
    'http' => array(
        'proxy' => 'tcp://191.96.x.xx:1212',
    ),
);
stream_context_set_default($aContext);
```

But when I test it using trace route it does not go through the proxy.
Traceroute - https://www.adayinthelifeof.nl/2010/07/30/creating-a-traceroute-program-in-php/

Also I tried using the environment variable  `http_proxy=http://proxy.example.com:8080` but id doesn't go through the proxy

Comment: unable to find anything much on it

Answer (score 1):

The `stream_context_set_default` sets the default context for *file* operations (e.g. `fopen`, `file_get_contents`), but you're trying to do *socket* operations with `socket_create`, etc - the two are very different.

If you just want to download files over HTTP via a proxy server use something like `$data = file_get_contents("http://example.com/file");` after you've set the default context to use your proxy.

If you need to be using raw sockets you can use `socket_create` etc, but you'll need to provide more details on what type of proxy you are using and what you want to achieve with sockets.